# Run all jobs in the same stage sequentially in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My goal is to manually start the stage so that the jobs is done sequentially.

My pipeline:

```
stages:
    - dev_docker

job-1:
    stage: dev_docker
    when: manual
    script: 
      - echo "job-1 started"
      - sleep 5
      - echo "job-1 done"

job-2:
    stage: dev_docker
    needs: ["job-1"]
    script: 
      - echo "job-2 started"
      - sleep 5
      - echo "job-2 done"

job-3:
    stage: dev_docker
    needs: ["job-2"]
    script: 
      - echo "job-3 started"
      - sleep 5
      - echo "job-3 done"

job-4:
    stage: dev_docker
    needs: ["job-3"]
    script: 
      - echo "job-4 started"
      - sleep 5
      - echo "job-4 done"
```

My problem is that after starting the second job, the rest of the jobs are not started.
[image]
[image]

My public pipeline: https://gitlab.com/Yatakoi/needs/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bug within GitLab itself, [someone here has the exact same issue as you](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/217129#note_826686713), with a WIP fix potentially on the way, as mentioned in the comment